# Grid is not changing after child elements are switched to collapsed or hidden

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visibility

I have a grid with 4 buttons. All 4 buttons are visible when starting my application. After a user action, buttons 1 to 3 are switch to collapsed/hidden. My goal is that the 3 buttons are no longer visible and the fourth button "spreads" over the whole grid (see the last picture in this post). Unfortunately my code does not work the way I want it to. :/

This is my code right now:

```
                <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   <Button Name="btn_1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Button 1"/>
                   <Button Name="btn_2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Button 2"/>
                   <Button Name="btn_3" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Button 3"/>
                   <Button Name="btn_4" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Button 4"/>
                </Grid>
```

This is the result of the code:

[image: View with all 4 button on visible]

If I set the visibillity of button 1 to 3 from visible to hidden or collapsed the view is the following:

[image]

What result I actually expected would be the following:

[image]

I also tried working with a dockpanel. Unfortunately also without success. Do I have to work with events or triggers?

I appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance.

**Edit - Solution:**

Switching the height of button 1 to 3 from `"*"` to `"auto"` is the solution.

```
                <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                      <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ControlRowDefinitionHeight}"/>
                      <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ControlRowDefinitionHeight}"/>
                      <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ControlRowDefinitionHeight}"/>
                      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                   <Button Name="btn_1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Button 1"/>
                   <Button Name="btn_2" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Button 2"/>
                   <Button Name="btn_3" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Button 3"/>
                   <Button Name="btn_4" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Button 4"/>
                </Grid>
```

I set the binding ControlRowDefinitionHeight (`public GridLength ControlRowDefinitionHeight`) to 
`new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)` in my code behind if all 4 buttons are visible. If only the fourth button is visible, ControlRowDefinitionHeight is set to `new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must also change the `Height` of the corresponding `RowDefinition`s from `*` to `Auto`, otherwise the grid will continue to evenly distribute its rows as we've observed.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution. See my edit for how I implemented this in my code.

Answer (score 1):

```
        **Try it by adding MinHeight="anything you like"**    
            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                  <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                  <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                  <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
               </Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <Button Name="btn_1" Grid.Row="0" MinHeight="20"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Button 1"/>
               <Button Name="btn_2" Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Button 2"/>
               <Button Name="btn_3" Grid.Row="2" MinHeight="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Button 3"/>
               <Button Name="btn_4" Grid.Row="3" MinHeight="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Button 4"/>
            </Grid>
```